# Lua displaying table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'v made a quiz with multiple choices. Before starting the game, a user has to use an identifier and then the user is added to the table and ready to play:

```
function addUser(msg)
  local id = msg.from.username
  if (userScore == nil) then
     userScore = {}
  end
  if (userScore[id]) then
     return "user already in Game"
  else
       userScore[id] = 100
     return id
  end
```

This adds the points in the table:

```
function addScore(msg)
  local id = msg.from.username

 if (userScore[id] == nil) then
     return "user unknown. start het spel!"
  end
 if (game == "on") then
     if (userScore[id]) then
        userScore[id] = userScore[id] - 1
         return id .. ", punje eraf!"
     else
       return id .. " is not yet a user! where to start huh?"
     end
  else
    return "Game mode is off"
  end
end
```

Then with !score the users can see the score:

```
elseif (matches[1] == "!score") then
  for k, v in pairs(userScore) do
   return k .. " : " ..  v
  end
```

The issue I have is that I only see one line in the table, knowing that other users are added to the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean `print(k .. " : " ..  v)`?

Comment: Nope, didn't solve it.. stil showing the first value. even if I add users in the via the script above.

Comment: @WouterMocking in the end of your explanation you use ```lua
for k, v in pairs(userScore) do
   return k .. " : " ..  v
  end
```
which returns the first key-value pair. If you are expecting it to return all of them then it will never do that it just returns one - the first it finds.
If you are printing or outputting the return value of that code it will just output that one key-value pair.

Comment: @rochet2 thx! What should I do to get the table returned like this: id - score - next line - id - score etc

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it seems you want to return a single string that contains the userScore table's key-value pairs on each line.

You can do this by constructing a string that has the lines.
For example like this:

```
local res = {}
for k, v in pairs(userScore) do
    table.insert(res, k .. " : " ..  v)
end
return table.concat(res, "\n")
```